# How to write a query get all infomation from one table to another one

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am building access database that will get data from a outside source and place it in a table that is link to the data source. As we all know that you are not allowed to recinfigure that linked table.

What I want to do is take that data from that that linked table and make another table that I will be able to add additional new fields and snyc the out that gets put into the linked table.

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on append queries:

http://www.databasedev.co.uk/append_query.html

In other SQL systems, this would  use some variant on "INSERT INTO" or "SELECT INTO"

Comment: I am still having a little bit of troble with this. Is there any standard procedure to do this because I know that this is a very common thing that you would have to do when you are feeding data to a database.

Comment: SO works best for highly targeted questions.  It isn't really very good for soliciting or writing tutorials, walk through or the like.  There are many videos illustrating how to do append queries: http://www.google.com/search?q=append%20query&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbo=u&tbs=vid:1&source=og&sa=N&hl=en&tab=wv

Answer (score 0):

The other alternative would be to use DoCmd.TransferDatabase to import the table. This can be done from any data source that Access can use via a linked table. It might be a little tricky figuring out the exact format for the connect string if it's not an Access table, though.